# Load Balancing Ethernet LAN & WIFI on linux?

Tags: networking, load-balancing, wifi

I have configured two internet connection to my Linux box, first Ethernet LAN with range 192.168.2.1 & WIFI with range 192.168.1.1 this both connection are connected to 2 different internet providers & now i want to use both connection at a time & load balance.

The following is the output of the `route -n` command:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: `route` is obsolete on Linux. Use `ip route` instead. Which, incidentally, have load balancing features, but which won't work in your case.

Comment: How to use ip route for load balancing & why it will not work in my case ? can you please explain me. Thank you

Comment: See the `ip route` manpage on `nexthop`. It won't work in your case, because each internet provider will give you an IP which can only be used with their network. `ip route`'s multipath requires that only one source address is used on both networks.